# AngularJS Service in directive being called twice

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I'm trying to figure out if my directive is being initialized twice instead of once and if there is a better way to initialize and watch for changes.

HTML code for my angular index.html:

```
<!-- Select drop down-->
<select name="selectcity" ng-model="selectedcity" ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in cities"></select>

<!--Directive-->
<div simple-chart chart-data="lineData"></div>
```

I have a directive that gets its data from an AJAX call via a service and then initializes the directive template like so,

```
MyService.getData(scope.selectedcity).then(
function (data) {
//code goes here
console.log("Initializing the template for the first time");
scope.lineData.push(data.info);
});
```

I have a select box where the user can change the city and then the directive needs to be updated to show the new citys information. I have coded my directive to track the changes like so,

```
scope.$watch('selectedcity', function (nv) {
    if (scope.lineData !== undefined) {
        //code goes here
        console.log("Going to change the city to, "+nv);
        //Going to call the service for the new city
        MyService.getData(nv).then(
            function (data) {
                //code goes here
                console.log("Initializing the template for the first time");
                scope.lineData.push(data.info);
            });
    }
});
```

I have noticed that when the page loads, both the functions above are called because the console prints,

```
Initializing the template for the first time
Going to change the city to, Chicago
```

1. Does it mean that the directive is being initialized twice?
2. Is there a way to call scope.$watch only when the value of the select drop-down changes (i.e. selected city changes)?
3. Do I need to initialize the value of 'selectedcity' to avoid the directive from being initialized twice?
4. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) you should check whether the `newValue !== oldValue` in your $watch expression:

```
scope.$watch('selectedcity', function (newValue, oldValue) {
  if (newValue && newValue !== oldValue) {
    // We have a new value set, and it's not the same as the old.
    // Do something
  }
}
```